# Casting movies from Linux PC Kodi to TV using Bubbleupnp and Chromecast dongle

Tags: kodi, chromecast

I can easily cast movies from my Android phone with Kodi to my tv dongle. Although it works I find this to be inconvenient because when my phone battery is low I plug it in to charge in a different room.

What I'd like is to be able to cast from my PC running Kodi and BubbleUPNP server. I think I'm missing some knowledge though. All of the guides I found while searching refer to using Android phone in some way.

For hardware I have a decent Linux PC with Kodi installed as well as BubbleUPNP server. BubbleUPNP server detects Kodi as a Media Server and a Media Renderer. Great! Now what?

There is a section in the docs about OpenHome renderers but I don't really understand it.

Is there a way to cast from my pc to the dongle without an intermediary Android phone?

Answer (score 0):

If your add-on has the ability to save to file while you watch, you can run this suite of python scripts on the result. 
https://github.com/Pat-Carter/stream2chromecast

Or if you setup an apache server (or expose it via another URL provider of some sort (lighttpd, python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080, etc,etc ) to your cache directory, and plop this set of html examples into it as well, you can stream almost instantly.
https://github.com/vickyg3/UrlPlayer

*I'm currently working on a native Kodi solution myself, but it's going to take a bit to figure out the ins and outs and migrate the Pat-Carter's python code into an addon/script. If you're techy savvy, this might be fairly easy to do.

For now, I personally use SMPlayer. (http://www.smplayer.info/en/downloads) while not a near enough kodi solution, it's how I found out about UrlPlayer. 
(may the stack and format gods not hurt me too badly? I'm still relatively new to answering.)

Comment: I use Plex but I think VLC can easily stream all your media throughout your network too.

Comment: VLC didn't have a chromecast ability for linux, at the time of this original reply. It was available for windows, but the addition hadn't been committed to  linux. Now it happily casts. Some people may need to go outside the mainline repositories to get the update, but it's well worth it, and they have a full set of instructions on how to add the PPA.